# PHP / MYSQL: Cannot view first data row after filter at PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a really weird issue in my code. To be short, I created a system that has a dashboard called `dashboard_engineer.php`. This dashboard will display only the first 30 data rows of the MySQL database. This dashboard also contains 3 filtered inputs which are:

- team
- date from
- date to

Users can use this filter to find their exact data rows. The user just fills in the input and presses the button <kbd>Search</kbd>, and this will redirect the user to `dashboard_engineer2.php`.

In this dashboard, all the filtered data rows will be displayed. Each data row contains a <kbd>View</kbd> and a <kbd>Remove</kbd> button. The <kbd>View</kbd> button is used to view the details of the data row.

**My problem is**, at the filtered data, the details in the first data rows that is displayed are empty when the <kbd>View</kbd> button is clicked. But, the details can be viewed for the second, third and following data rows as the user clicks on the <kbd>View</kbd> button. When I inspected the first row's <kbd>View</kbd> button, the `ID` of that button is correct.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this will be appreciated.

#### Here's my current code

**dashboard_engineer.php**

```
  <form method = 'post' action = 'dashboard_engineer2.php' target="_blank">
    <td width="40%">
      <select class="form-control"  name="team" id="team" required>
        <option value="">Please select...</option>
        <?php foreach ($data as $row2): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row2["team_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row2["fullname"]; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="1%"></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="from" id="from" class="form-control" placeholder="From" required></td>
    <td width="1%"></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="form-control" placeholder="To" required></td>
    <td width="1%"></td>
    <td width="10%"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary" >Search</button><td>
  </form>
  </tr>
</table><br>
<div class="row" style='height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;'>
  <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
    <?php

    $query = $conn->query("SELECT TOP 30 * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid WHERE ot_users.team_id <> 1 AND ot_report.status = 'yes'  ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC");
    $query -> execute();
    $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if(empty($results)){

      echo "<table class = 'table-bordered' width ='100%'>";
      echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th width = '5%'>id</th>
            <th width = '17%'>Date</th>
            <th width = '27%'>Officer/ Asst. Engineer</th>
            <th width = '32%'>Task Name</th>
            <th width = '12%'>Status</th>
            <th width = '7%'>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
        <tr>
        <td colspan='8'>No report at this moment</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>";
    }else{

          echo "<table class = 'table-bordered' width ='100%'>";
          echo "<thead>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th width = '5%'>id</th>
                <th width = '17%'>Date</th>
                <th width = '27%'>Officer/ Asst. Engineer</th>
                <th width = '32%'>Task Name</th>
                <th width = '12%'>Status</th>
                <th colspan = '2' width = '7%'>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody >";

            $query = $conn->query("SELECT TOP 30 * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid WHERE ot_users.team_id <> 1 AND ot_report.status = 'yes' ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC");
            while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $status=$row['report_status'];
            if($status=="Pending")
            {
              $color="color:blue";
            }
            else 
            {
                $color="color:green";
            }

            $report_id = $row['report_id'];
            $datereport = $row['report_date'];
            $datereport2 = strtotime($datereport);
            $report_date = date('d M Y', $datereport2);
            $fullname = $row['fullname'];
            $task_name = $row['task_name'];


            echo "<tr>";

              echo "<td>". $report_id. "</td>";
              echo "<td>". $report_date . "</td>";
              echo "<td>". $fullname . "</td>";
              echo "<td>". $task_name . "</td>";

              echo "<td align='center' style='$color'><strong>". $status . "</strong></td>";
              echo "<td align='center'>";
                echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'view_task/view_task.php' target='_blank'>";
                  echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'report_id' value = '".$report_id."'>";
                  echo "<button type = 'submit' class='btn-primary'>View</button>";
                echo "</form>";

              echo "</td>";
              echo "<td align='center'>";
                echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'remove.php' onClick=\"return confirm('Do you want to remove this report?')\">";
                  echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'report_id' value = '".$report_id."'>";
                  echo "<button type = 'submit' class='btn-danger'>Remove</button>";
                echo "</form>";
              echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</tbody>";
          echo "</table><br>";  
    }
    ?>
```

**dashboard_engineer2.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST["from"], $_REQUEST["to"], $_REQUEST["team"])){

  $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
  $to   = $_REQUEST['to'];
  $team = $_REQUEST['team'];

  $result = '';
  $query = "SELECT * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid WHERE ot_users.team_id = '".$team."' AND report_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."' ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC";

  $sql = $conn->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
  $sql -> execute();

    if($sql->rowCount() > 0){

      echo'

      <form method="post" action="">
      <div><a href="../pdf.php?from='.$from.'&to='.$to.' &team='.$team.'" target="_blank"><u>PDF View</u></a></div><br>
      <div class="row" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">
      <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
      <table class = "table-bordered" width = "100%">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th width = "10%"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAl"> All</th>
      <th width = "3%">id</th>
      <th width = "15%">Date</th>
      <th width = "25%">Supervisor</th>
      <th width = "30%">Task Name</th>
      <th width = "10%">Status</th>
      <th colspan = "2" width = "7%">Action</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>';

        $i=0;

        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

          $datereport = $row['report_date'];
          $datereport2 = strtotime($datereport);
          $report_date = date('d M Y', $datereport2);

          $status=$row['report_status'];

          if($status=="Pending"){
            $color="color:blue";
          }
          else {
            $color="color:green";
          }

          $report_id = $row["report_id"];

          echo'<tr>';
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" name="check[]" value='.$row['report_id'].'></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$report_id.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$report_date.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row["fullname"].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row["task_name"].'</td>';
            echo '<td align="center" style='.$color.'><strong>'.$status.'</strong></td>';
            echo '<td align="center">';
            echo '<form action = "view_task/view_task.php" method = "post" target="_blank">';
            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "report_id" value = "'.$report_id.'">';
            echo '<button type = "submit" class="btn-primary">View</button>';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</td>';
            // echo '<a class="btn-view btn-primary btn-sm" href="view_task/view_task.php?report_id='. $report_id .'" data-toggle="tooltip" >View</a></td>';
            echo '<td align="center">';
            echo "<form action = 'remove2.php' method = 'post' onClick=\"return confirm('Do you want to remove this reports?')\">";
              echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "from" value = "'.$from.'">';
              echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "to" value = "'.$to.'">';
              echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "team" value = "'.$team.'">';
              echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "report_id" value = "'.$report_id.'">';
              echo '<button type = "submit" class="btn-danger">Remove</button>';
            echo '</form>';

            echo '</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
          $i++;

        }
          echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><p align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn-danger btn-sm" name="save">DELETE</button></p></td>';
          echo '</tr>';
          echo '</form>';

      }
      else
      {
        echo '
        <table class = "table-bordered" width = "100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th width = "5%">id</th>
        <th width = "12%">Date</th>
        <th width = "29%">Supervisor</th>
        <th width = "23%">Task Name</th>
        <th width = "7%">From</th>
        <th width = "7%">To</th>
        <th width = "10%">Status</th>
        <th width = "7%">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="8">No report found</td>
        </tr>';
      }
      echo '</body></table></div></div>';

      } 

      ?>
```

viewtask/view_task.php

```
<?php

  include("../../../../config/configPDO.php");
  include("../../../../config/check.php");


  $team_n = $_SESSION['team_n'];

  if (isset ($_POST['report_id'])) {
      $report_id = $_POST['report_id'];
  }else if (isset ($_GET['report_id'])){
      $report_id = $_GET['report_id'];
  }else {
      exit ("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Not allowed!'); location.href = '../dashboard_engineer.php';</script>");
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid LEFT JOIN ot_team ON ot_team.team_id = ot_users.team_id WHERE report_id = :report_id";
  $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));
  while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

      $report_id = $row["report_id"];
      $report_date = $row["report_date"];
      $task_name = $row["task_name"];
      $photo_before = $row["photo_before"];
      $photo_after = $row["photo_after"];
      $ot_start = $row["ot_start"];
      $ot_end = $row["ot_end"];
      $time_photo_before = $row["time_photo_before"];
      $time_photo_after = $row["time_photo_after"];
      $report_status = $row["report_status"];

  }

?>

 <table align="center" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><b>Date Report</b></td>
      <td width="80%" colspan='3'><?php echo $report_date; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <form action="update_task_name.php" method="POST" >
      <td><b>Task Name</b></td>
      <td colspan = '2'><input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name" value="<?php echo $task_name; ?>"/></td>
      <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="<?php echo $report_id ?>"> 
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?')">Save</button></td>
    </form>
    </tr>
    <form action="update_photo_before.php" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan = '3'><b>Before Task</b></td>

      <?php
        if(!isset($photo_before) || empty($photo_before)) {
            echo "<td colspan='2' rowspan='2'><img id='output_before' src='../../../../images/faces/noimage.png'/ style='width:220px;height:300px;'></td>";
          }else{ 
                  echo "<td colspan='2' rowspan='2'><img id='output_before' src='$photo_before'/ style='width:220px;height:300px;'></td>"; 
          }
      ?>

      <td colspan ='2'><input type="file" name="uploadFile" value="" accept="image/*" onchange="preview_before(event)"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="<?php echo $report_id ?>"> 
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?')"/></td>

    </tr>
    </form>
    <tr>
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 30 * FROM` isn't a MySQL syntax. Check your server error log for errors. `SELECT ... ORDER BY x LIMIT 30` is probably want you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT TOP 30 * FROM` isn't a MySQL syntax. Check your server error log for errors. `SELECT ... ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC LIMIT 30` is probably want you want.